# JLabels don't show when button clicked

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I want to see labels when my show Button clicked, But don't work!

```
public class d4 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

Connection con;
String dbName = "mydb";
String bdUser = "root";
String dbPassword = "2323";
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb";
JButton showButton;
static JLabel[] lbl;
JPanel panel;

public d4() {

try {
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, bdUser, dbPassword);
    System.out.println("Connected to database successfully!");

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.out.println("Could not connect to database");
}

add(mypanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(400, 500);
setLocation(300, 30);
setVisible(true);
pack();
}

public JPanel mypanel() {
panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
showButton = new JButton("Show");
showButton.addActionListener(this);
panel.add(showButton);
revalidate();
repaint();

return panel;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
if (e.getSource() == showButton) {
            lbl = recordsLabel();
        for(JLabel jlabel : lbl){
            panel.add(jlabel);  
}
}
public JLabel[] recordsLabel() {
try {
    Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet result1 = st1.executeQuery("select * from mytable");
    ArrayList<String> lableList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (result1.next()) {
        String resultRow = result1.getString(1) + " " + result1.getString(2);
        System.out.println(resultRow);
        lableList.add(resultRow);
    }
    Object[] arrayResultRow = lableList.toArray();

    int rows = result1.last() ? result1.getRow() : 0;

    lbl = new JLabel[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        lbl[i] = new JLabel(arrayResultRow[i].toString());
    }

} catch (SQLException sqle) {
    System.out.println("Can not excute sql statement");
}
return lbl;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
new d4();
}
}
```

Comment: Every time I see someone put `// What do here?` it totally tells me you haven't tried anything.

Comment: @Tdorno i tried so many times, But not work!

Comment: You now need to do some debugging to find out where the error is -- to see if the sql statements are working, if the JLabels are being made, etc... Either step through your code with a debugger checking the state of variables, or use println statements (or logging) to check the state of variables in the critical portions of code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels all sql statements are works correctly, But just labels not shown!

Comment: This would be much easier to read (and therefore help) with proper code indentation.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `myPanel()` **twice**, and by doing this, you're adding JLabels to a JPanel that is never added to the GUI.

Solution: don't do this. Your `myPanel()` is kind of screwy to begin with since it returns a JPanel and also sets the class field panel at the same time. So set the panel variable once, and then use the variable.

And yes, `revalidate()` and `repaint()` the container after adding components to it as per Azad's recommendations (1+ to him).

Comment: +1, I was about adding the first part of the answer to mine :).

Comment: I use `revalidate()` and `repain()` methods and use `mypanel()` once , Now there are no exception, But lables are not shown!

Comment: @Sajjad: You need to simplify your problem for yourself and for us. Create a small program with no database code in it, but with only dummy hard-coded data and try to add the dummy data to JLabels on button press with this small program. If it doesn't work, then post the new code as an addendum to your question above. Please be sure to only post well formatted code so we don't have to struggle to read and understand it. Note that in all likelihood, you should be showing the database data in a JTable, not in JLabels, especially if you need to display more than one row of data.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels this is my first program to going to show data in JTable.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels How show my problem with less code? My problem is about swing(show jlabels on frame when button selected), But now i don't know how show this problem (for e.x `recordsLabel()` method) without JDBC.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I think that my main problem is implementing my showButton ActionListener...

Comment: @Sajjad-: I'm not saying "with less code" but rather with ***better*** code, with only code that is relevant to your problem. Your current problem doesn't involve database processing since you state that that part is working. So show us code without any database code in it, with hard-coded data, a small program that we can run, compile, and that shows us your problem. Note that you aren't required to do this, but if you do, you have a better chance of getting a satisfying solution -- up to you.

Answer (score 5):

You have not implemented the ActionListener interface

EDIT: your updated code shows that you have. Now as Hovercraft Full Of Eels suggests, the next step is to isolate the problem with debugging techniques.

Comment: Your class claims that it implements it, but it doesn't really.

Comment: -1, that's not the OP need, and good to notice that he forgot implementing, but at the end, that's not causing the problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Good to know that and thanks for the upvote, I will remove the down vote if he update his answer, so that, someone comes and see this answer don't be confused.

Answer (score 4):

Try calling `revalidate()` and `repaint()` after adding the lables to the panel, you need also to call `pack()` on the frame for resizing the frame to fit the new components.